# Sample size for SHAP explainer and range of a SHAP value

Tags: machine-learning, classification, predictive-modeling, random-forest, shap

I am working on a binary classification with 977 records with 77:23 class proportion. I used random forest model.

Based on my attempt to run SHAP package, I got the below plots

[image]

And I also see that SHAP requires us to select sample size to get the SHAP value as shown here in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71599628/how-to-export-shap-local-explanations-to-dataframe/71606106?noredirect=1#comment126564761_71606106)

When SHAP does not use same assumption as LIME neighborhood, why does it require sample size to be mentioned?

To summarize, my questions are as follows

a) Based on my plot above, is my feature contribution very less? Should the contribution magnitude be greater than 1 to be considered as important feature (with some predictive power) or the scale of x-axis differs based on different project? While it shows,0.20,0.12,0.11,0.5 etc. how do I know whether they have sufficient predictive power?  Here in SHAP website I see that they have values more than 0.5 etc. Is the range specific to that problem or SHAP values usually have a common range and my features make very less contribution?

b) Additionally, why do we sample size to be given to compute the SHAP value?

Comment: I think the comments on [the answer to your SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71606106/10495893) answer your question (b): computational expense.

Comment: The answer to (a) depends on the model type and response; is it regression, or classification? If the former, the scale of the targets is important. If the latter, I think you can get shap values in the log-odds space or the probability space?

Comment: It's binary classification..

Comment: Feature contributions are measured on raw scale. The only info you can infer  from the plot is that top feature is more powerful in terms of shapley values than the next one (given model and data). "very less": can you clarify what do you mean?

Comment: And to be fair (b) quoted here should be attributed to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64828997/4317058) by @Ben

Comment: In the SHAP documentation, all these plot have values in the range of >0.5 and <2 something.. But in my case, all is less than 0.5... So, how do I whether they have predictive power or not... Of course, my AUC is 84 but my minority class F1 is 60. So, I would like to know (if you have time) whether how the mean SHAP value is calculated (and how the range is determined).

Comment: To test for predictive power try (1) to predict with and without the feature of interest (2) choose a metric (3) test the change in metric for statistical significance

Comment: Another possible way is to test SV themselves for statistical significance. For that you would need to calculate not only point estimates but deviations as well. But I never saw anybody doing that. And there might be a reason for not doing that.

Comment: I have created a new post (in relation to SHAP), can help me with this if you have time?  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/569199/what-is-the-use-of-expected-value-in-ml-models